# Display realtime server data on webpage

Tags: javascript, cpu-usage, system-variable

I would need to display realtime server informations on a webpage such as cpu load and such things. the more i can display the better it is. There is no restriction in the programming Language, but if it could be javascript it would be better. All samples i found use node.js to get the client informations, but none to get the server informations. At a later stage i would needto access the hardware IO of the server (a Raspberry) so this could be taken into account too.

A plus would be to display the realtime mouse position on the server as this would help me out on future implementations too.

Thanks

Comment: @DannyBeckett i know, but if there is no starting point because all i found refers to something different (as mentioned) there is nothing i can post. Sorry

Comment: why not use meta tag? to refresh the page?

Comment: @Hadash it needs to be fast. almost realtime.. The page is inside the network so thats not a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd highly recommend the open-source script [phpSysInfo](https://github.com/rk4an/phpsysinfo); it's been around for years now.

Here's [a demo](http://phpsysinfo.sourceforge.net/phpsysinfo/index.php?disp=dynamic) - enjoy!

Comment: thanks, but as far as i understand it does not update in realtime.. or am i wrong?

Comment: It *does* indeed update in realtime.

Comment: OK thanks checking it out!

Answer (score 0):

```
 for cpu usage, OperatingSystemMXBean.getSystemLoadAverage() /     
 OperatingSystemMXBean.getAvailableProcessors() (load average per cpu)
 for memory, OperatingSystemMXBean.getTotalPhysicalMemorySize() and     
 OperatingSystemMXBean.getFreePhysicalMemorySize()
 for disk space, File.getTotalSpace() and File.getUsableSpace()
  Limitations:

 The getSystemLoadAverage() and disk space querying methods are only available under Java
  6. Also, some JMX functionality may not be available to all platforms (i.e. it's been   
  reported that getSystemLoadAverage() returns -1 on Windows).
```

also check this .You can make a server side call via ajax and get the information from server side and can display.This code is in java .

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html

Comment: thanks, woudl it also be possible to display the realtime mouse position on the server? simply XY coordinates?